# How to zip a branch containing source files exclusing .exe in peforce

Tags: perforce, perforce-branch-spec

can someone help me to find how to zip a folder/branch containing source files excluding .exe in perforce

Comment: Your zip tool may have an option to exclude files on its own. For Info-Zip's zip, this option at the end of the command line should work: `-x *.exe` If you are working from a GUI there may be an exclude files field you can enter `*.exe` into.

Answer (score 2):

First question would be why is there an exe in your Perforce?

Is it a 3rd party exe or the output of your build?

First you would start with a clientspec, for example:

```
Client: narain_win
Owner:  narain
Description:
        Client spec to create Zip version
Root:   null
Options:        nomodtime noclobber
SubmitOptions:  
View:
        //depot/my_branch/...     "//narain_win/c:/Zip Release/..."
```

Then, use the hyphen to modify the view to remove your exe files, for example:

```
-//depot/my_branch/....exe "//narain_win/c:/Zip Release/..."
```

Then, you would need a command line operation to

1. Sync the client spec
2. Zip the files

For the first item, you can check [p4 sync](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.2/manuals/cmdref/sync.html), but you will have to have the right clientspec selected, which can be done by calling `p4 -c clientname cmd`.

Once everything is sync, use whatever command line zip tool you have, such as WinZip, 7Zip, etc... there are many alternatives.